# The last element (bitstring.BitArray) in list is incorrect after XORing python

Tags: python-3.x, xor, bitstring

I have snippet of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from bitstring import BitArray
import itertools

# Helper functions

def get_bitset_by_letter(letter, encoding):
    return encoding[letter] if letter in encoding else None

def get_letter_by_bitset(bitset, encoding):
    for letter, encoding_bitset in encoding.items():
        if bitset == encoding_bitset:
            return letter

    return None

class Word():
    def __init__(self, word, encoding):
        self.encoding = encoding
        self.as_word = ''
        self.as_bits = []

        if isinstance(word, str):
            self.as_word = word
            self._encode_to_bits()
        elif all(isinstance(i, BitArray) for i in word):
            self.as_bits = word
            self._decode_to_word()
        else:
            raise('class Word: Unexpected type of word arg')

    def __ixor__(self, other):
        for index, bitset in enumerate(other.as_bits):
            print('In XOR: %d-%s-%s' % (index, self.as_bits[index], bitset))
            self.as_bits[index] ^= bitset
        return self

    def as_bits(self):
        return self.as_bits

    def as_word(self):
        return self.as_word

    def _encode_to_bits(self):
        for letter in self.as_word:
            bitset = get_bitset_by_letter(letter, self.encoding)
            if bitset is None:
                raise('Can not find bitset by given letter %s in encoding.' % str(letter))
            else:
                self.as_bits.append(bitset)

    def _decode_to_word(self):
        for bitset in self.as_bits:
            letter = get_letter_by_bitset(bitset, self.encoding)
            if letter is None:
                raise('Can not find letter by given bitset %s in encoding.' % str(bitset))
            else:
                self.as_word += letter

def main():
    encoding = {
        'A': BitArray(bin='000'),
        'B': BitArray(bin='001'),
        'C': BitArray(bin='010'),
        'D': BitArray(bin='011'),
        'E': BitArray(bin='100'),
        'F': BitArray(bin='101'),
        'G': BitArray(bin='110'),
        'H': BitArray(bin='111'),
    }

    print(encoding)
    print()

    word_1 = Word('ABCHE', encoding)
    print('word_1 = %s' % word_1.as_bits)
    word_2 = Word('FGDEA', encoding)
    print('word_2 = %s' % word_2.as_bits)
    word_1 ^= word_2
    print(word_1.as_bits)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Details: I use `bitstring.BitArray` class to represent letter as set of three bits and code words this way (some kind of hometask). Also, my code should be able to do XOR for this words.
Problem: Every last element for `other.as_bits` list has incorrect value, when it arrives to function. If I comment the line

```
#self.as_bits[index] ^= bitset
```

the last value of the `other.as_bits` is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the output (python 3.5.2):

```
{'C': BitArray('0b010'), 'B': BitArray('0b001'), 'G': BitArray('0b110'), 
'F': BitArray('0b101'), 'A': BitArray('0b000'), 'H': BitArray('0b111'), 
'D': BitArray('0b011'), 'E': BitArray('0b100')}

word_1 = [BitArray('0b000'), BitArray('0b001'), BitArray('0b010'), BitArray('0b111'), BitArray('0b100')]

word_2 = [BitArray('0b101'), BitArray('0b110'), BitArray('0b011'), BitArray('0b100'), BitArray('0b000')]

In XOR: 0-0b000-0b101

In XOR: 1-0b001-0b110

In XOR: 2-0b010-0b011

In XOR: 3-0b111-0b100

In XOR: 4-0b100-0b101

[BitArray('0b101'), BitArray('0b111'), BitArray('0b001'), BitArray('0b011'), BitArray('0b001')]
```

From this you can see, that the last 4th element of `word_2` in `__ixor__` is `0b101`, should be `0b000`

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I solved this using `__xor__` instead of `__ixor__`.